# Upcoming events.. a birthday?

Tags: support, chat

Maybe I have been blind for a few years, but this seems.. *unique* - what's the dealio?

[image]

Seems like it would be private -

[image]

Comment: I happened to mention in chat (Root Access) some time ago that my birthday was on Jan 22. Someone (I can't remember who) decided to create a chat event as a reminder so that the chat regulars could wish me a happy birthday ;) This morning the event appeared on the [su] upcoming events. So, as a room owner, I deleted the event. However it still appears as you have noted in your question :/

Comment: Ah! I was worried that there was some sort of bug, but it did lead me to chat so I wasn't sure.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with any private information as the event was manually created.

Comment: All in all, it's quite amusing. I don't think anyone expected a chat event to be widely advertised ;)

Comment: @Sathya, do you happen to know how to remove it from "Upcoming Events"? (not that I particularly mind people knowing my birthday ... it just seems strange to have it advertised there)

Comment: @DavidPostill You're famous! :P

Comment: @DavidPostill the chat event spawns a community event on the main site but deleting one does not delete the other. I've deleted the community event  now.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill its a pity really. I was looking forward to a sitewide celebration. We need some community events to get people together more.

Comment: @Mokubai You have my permission to put it back ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the [chat] regulars thought it would be a fun thing to plan a Birthday Event for DavidPostill. Ended up on the front screen, and I couldn't contain myself when people asked why... So I spilled the beans!

Comment: Do you know how many candles you need for the virtual cake?

Comment: dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/birthdaycake/candles bs=??